# CSS Nav Menu issue

Tags: css

I'm not able to get CSS property "margin-top" to work consistently across all broswers (IE, FireFox, Chrome).

```
.navmenu { list-style: none; padding: 0px; margin-top:16px; }
```

This works fine in FireFox and Chrome, but does nothing in Internet Explorer.

An example can be seen here : http://www.pogocheats.net/template.php

Nav CSS can be found at : http://www.pogocheats.net/styles/test.css (starting at line : 276)

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Try to set to that element: `position:relative;` and than instead of `margin-top` use `top:16px;`

Comment: or remove the `margin-top:16px;` from .navmenu property and add `padding-top:16px` to the containing TD#navbar.

Comment: Still no luck on both suggestions - they work great in IE, FF but push the nav manu too far down in chrome. Refresh template for details.

Comment: Best to insert a CSS reset before your own CSS code like Diodeus mentioned. Otherwise some elements will always have random margin, padding or border in one browser or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules for list-based menus:

1) [Use a CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

2) Don't style the LI, other than `position:` `float:` or `display:`

3) Put all styling on the A-tag and use `display:block`

4) Clear your floats (if using them)

See my list tutorial: [preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists](http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists)